# Text areas and hyperlinks?

Tags: c#, winforms, text, hyperlink

I have two quick, easy questions on C# in Visual Studio. First, is there anything like the label, but for an area of text in the program? I would like to have multiple lines of text in my program, but can only seem to accomplish it with a DotNetBar label with wordwrap turned on.

Second, is there any way to have a hyperlink in the middle of the text without using a link label? If I wanted to generate text like "An update is available, please visit http://example.com to download it!", is it possible to make the link clickable without having to position a link label in the middle of the text?

Comment: Web application? Windows application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [LinkLabel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx) and set its [LinkArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linkarea.aspx) property:

```
 //LinkArea (start index, length)
 myLinkLabel.LinkArea = new LinkArea(37, 18);
 myLinkLabel.Text = "An update is available, please visit http://example.com to download it!";
```

The above will make the `http://example.com` a link whilst the rest of the text in normal.

Edit to answer comment:
There are various ways of handling the link. One way is to give the link a description (the URL) and then launch the URL using Process.Start.

```
myLinkLabel.LinkArea = new System.Windows.Forms.LinkArea(37, 18);
myLinkLabel.LinkClicked += new LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(myLinkLabel_LinkClicked);
myLinkLabel.Text = "An update is available, please visit http://example.com to download it!";       
myLinkLabel.Links[0].Description = "http://example.com";
```

And the event handler can read the description and launch the site:

```
void myLinkLabel_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(e.Link.Description);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the link isn't working though when I click it. Also, could you update the answer to include that I can, as kishorejangid said, set the autoresize property to false to make it multi-lined.

Answer (score 2):

You may try `RichTextBox` control.

```
string text = "This is the extract of text located at http://www.google.com and http://www.yahoo.com";
richTextBox1.Text   = text;

richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;
richTextBox1.LinkClicked += (sa, ea) =>
{
 System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ea.LinkText);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the white background the richtextbox has, and I can't change it to transparen.t

Comment: @Walkerneo - Yes can't change transparent. set richTextBox1.BackColor = this.BackColor; (parent control background)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal label and make the `AutoSize` property as false.
And then adjust your width and height it will wrap by it self

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using doing a windows application, and not a web application.

In C# you can create a normal textbox by dragging and dropping it onto your form, change its property to multi-line, and make it read only. Thats what I always do.

As for adding a link to the text without a linklabel. There is a way to add links to textboxes. You can check out a pretty good tutorial at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/LinkTextBox.aspx/